# Error 550006 with Android SDK for PayPal

Tags: android, paypal, in-app-billing

I am creating an android app with PayPal android SDK. 
The app on developer console is approved, and I have changed the client ID and the email to live configuration.

I am getting an error "System error 550006" when sending the payment.

Has anybody seen this and have a resolution ?

Comment: I could not find any list of error codes that refers to this error code on PayPal developers site. There is another post that refers to this error code but it does not have much info either.

Comment: for anyone that might stumble on this, PayPal has acknowledged that there is an issue that needs fixed on their end. They are working in rolling out a fix. per the support request update.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved as of the latest Android SDK.  Please ensure you have the latest SDK (1.0.3 or later).  Thanks!